# Change language or content of Mapbox cooperative Gestures overlay

Tags: mapbox

I'm using the "disable zoom while scrolling" option from mapbox with the cooperativeGestures [parameter](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cooperative-gestures/), which is working fine.

Since I'm working on a multilanguage page, I'm trying to alter the overlay text shown when scrolling the window.

Is there an automatic way of translation or is it possible to translate it manually?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **locale** property:

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
  center: [-74.5, 40],
  zoom: 9,
  locale: {
    "ScrollZoomBlocker.CtrlMessage": "Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map",
    "ScrollZoomBlocker.CmdMessage": "Use ⌘ + scroll to zoom the map"
  },
});
```

Full list of parameters that can be translated:

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
  center: [-74.5, 40],
  zoom: 9,
  locale: {
    "AttributionControl.ToggleAttribution": "Toggle attribution",
    "AttributionControl.MapFeedback": "Map feedback",
    "FullscreenControl.Enter": "Enter fullscreen",
    "FullscreenControl.Exit": "Exit fullscreen",
    "GeolocateControl.FindMyLocation": "Find my location",
    "GeolocateControl.LocationNotAvailable": "Location not available",
    "LogoControl.Title": "Mapbox logo",
    "Map.Title": "Map",
    "NavigationControl.ResetBearing": "Reset bearing to north",
    "NavigationControl.ZoomIn": "Zoom in",
    "NavigationControl.ZoomOut": "Zoom out",
    "ScrollZoomBlocker.CtrlMessage": "Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map",
    "ScrollZoomBlocker.CmdMessage": "Use ⌘ + scroll to zoom the map",
    "TouchPanBlocker.Message": "Use two fingers to move the map",
  },
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you a lot! I've tried to scan the docs to find this information but I haven't found anything. Would you mind sharing the/a link?

Comment: On this page: [https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/?q=locale&size=n_10_n](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/?q=locale&size=n_10_n). use Ctrl+F and type **options.locale**.

Comment: What if we want to change the language dynamically?